# How to read Feature Based Grammar from a string

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

To read Context Free Grammars we can use

```
nltk.CFG.fromstring(""" 
S-> NP VP`...
    """)
```

But it can't read a feature based grammar which is like?

```
S -> NP[NUM=?n] VP[NUM=?n]
```

So how to read feature based grammar from a string without actually having to save it in a fcfg file to load it later?

Answer (score 1):

You need to take care of NP and VP expansion production.

```
# ###################
# Grammar Productions
# ###################
# S expansion productions
S -> NP[NUM=?n] VP[NUM=?n]
# NP expansion productions
NP[NUM=?n] -> N[NUM=?n]
NP[NUM=?n] -> PropN[NUM=?n]
NP[NUM=?n] -> Det[NUM=?n] N[NUM=?n]
NP[NUM=pl] -> N[NUM=pl]
# VP expansion productions
VP[TENSE=?t, NUM=?n] -> IV[TENSE=?t, NUM=?n]
VP[TENSE=?t, NUM=?n] -> TV[TENSE=?t, NUM=?n] NP
```